# interItemSpacing = .fixed(0) not always working in UICollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with the interItemSpacing in my compositional layout. I have a layout group for each row that holds a couple of layout items (each has a different fractional width). I have set `layoutGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(0)`

Sometimes there is a one pixel line between items, although all items' fractionalWidths perfectly add up to 1.0. I calculate those fractional widths dynamically, depending on the content of the cell. An example:

```
Item 1: 0.2244798445859886
Item 2: 0.0999484835067196
Item 3: 0.2255459136606516
Item 4: 0.2244798445859886
Item 5: 0.2255459136606516
```

As you can see in the screenshot, there is a small space between the last two items:
[image]

The strange thing is that this issues does not always occur. It appears to depend on the collection view size. Maybe some sort of internal rounding issue? Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Can you post your collection view delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to rounding...

When the collection view lays out its cells, it rounds the x, y, width and height values to match the screen scale.

So, let's say your collection view width is `375` and, for the second cell, you say:

```
I want a cell width of 0.0999484835067196 * 375
```

which equals `37.48068131501985`

On a @2x device (such as iPhone 8), that value will be rounded to the nearest **one-half** ... in this case `37.5`

On a @3x device (such as iPhone 12 Pro), that value will be rounded to the nearest **one-third** ... in this case `37.3333333333...`

Using your array of widths, on an iPhone 8 with a collection view width of `375`, examining the cells after they've been laid-out results in this:

```
Cell: 0   Array: 0.2244798445859886   Calc: 84.17994171974573   Actual: 84.0
Cell: 1   Array: 0.0999484835067196   Calc: 37.48068131501985   Actual: 37.5
Cell: 2   Array: 0.2255459136606516   Calc: 84.57971762274435   Actual: 84.5
Cell: 3   Array: 0.2244798445859886   Calc: 84.17994171974573   Actual: 84.0
Cell: 4   Array: 0.2255459136606516   Calc: 84.57971762274435   Actual: 84.5

Collection View Width:  375.0
Array Sum:              1.0
Calculated Sum:         375.0
Actual Sum:             374.5
```

As you see,

- your specified percentages add up to `1.0`
- your Calculated values add up to `375`
- but... the *Actual* cell widths only add up to `374.5`

which leaves an extra 1/2 point to be filled in, thus the "extra space."

You don't see this all the time, likely because you're running on different devices with different widths and screen-scales.

For example, if your collection view width is `360-pts`, you get this:

```
Cell: 0   Array: 0.2244798445859886   Calc: 80.8127440509559    Actual: 81.0
Cell: 1   Array: 0.0999484835067196   Calc: 35.981454062419054  Actual: 36.0
Cell: 2   Array: 0.2255459136606516   Calc: 81.19652891783458   Actual: 81.0
Cell: 3   Array: 0.2244798445859886   Calc: 80.8127440509559    Actual: 81.0
Cell: 4   Array: 0.2255459136606516   Calc: 81.19652891783458   Actual: 81.0
Collection View Width:  360.0
Array Sum:              1.0
Calculated Sum:         360.0
Actual Sum:             360.0
```

and there's no "extra one-half point" needed.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Rounding indeed solves the issue. I was using fractional widths expecting that this would be automatically handled, but obviously I was wrong.